# protobuf and .net - how do I use the generated .cs file?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm starting to work with protobufs - I have a proto file:

```
syntax = "proto2";

message InputState {
    required uint32 input = 1;
    required string state = 2;
}

message InputStateData {
    repeated InputState input = 1;
}
```

I ran the command line tool (from protoc-3.0.0-alpha-3-win32)

I got this unexpected .cs file:  [!click me! Input.cs](https://bitbucket.org/jca_engineering/c-example/src/66a899fb0afc4f08aee2fe1db1f5438b36290dcc/protoc-3.0.0-alpha-3-win32/Inputs.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

I included the nuget protobuf-portable-net, but now I've no idea how to use the generated .cs file

What do I do next - is the Input.cs file correct?

Comment: Add the file to your `.csproj` and use it.

Comment: @Dai Check the Input.cs, the file is not usable in c# from what i can see

Comment: What makes you think it's unusable? It looks fine to me.

Comment: @Dai that dosn't compile when I include it in a c# project

Comment: I tried this https://silentorbit.com/protobuf/examples/ and the output was complete different and compiled - I must be misunderstanding something with the official tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two completely separate tools (at least) in .net that talk "protobuf". It looks like you're using the *tooling* from one (Jon's version, which used to be " protobuf-csharp-port", but which is now part of the Google codebase IIRC), but using the library from the other (protobuf-net). That won't work! The tooling an library must match.

If you want to use protobuf-net: either use the protobuf-net library by itself (it supports "code first", meaning: no tooling), or use the protobuf-net tooling with the protobuf-net library.

If you want to use protobuf-csharp-port (which now might just be "protobuf"): use the tooling from that, and the library from that.

For info, for the code-first approach with protobuf-net, you can translate simple contracts manually if you don't want to have to use build steps:

```
[ProtoContract]
class InputState {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public uint Input {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string State {get;set;}
}
[ProtoContract]
class InputStateData {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<InputState> Input {get;} = new List<InputState>();
}
```

Comment: thanks! I was hoping you would give your input. The Example you post was what I expected the generators to create. Are there generators that can do this? Also, why does the protoc tool generate such a complex file?

Comment: @pogorman the `protogen` tool in protobuf-net outputs something like this; as for "why": because that is how protoc is designed to work

Comment: I want to communicate with an embedded system (software written in C). The structs that will be communicated will always be defined on the embedded side. We will use nanopb on the embedded side. My hope was to use the proto files from the embedded and generate the classes like you posted above. Is this even possible? Or should I just go with the standard protoc tool? What do you think is the bests c# file generator to use? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I'm learning more, this is the file generator that gives the format closest to what I expected: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/protogen (for use with protobuf-net). This is exactly what I need.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool. 
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Generated from: inputs.proto
namespace inputs
{
[global::System.Serializable,  global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"InputState")]
 public partial class InputState : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
{
public InputState() {}

private uint _input;
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true, Name=@"input", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
public uint input
{
  get { return _input; }
  set { _input = value; }
}
private string _state;
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = true, Name=@"state", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
public string state
{
  get { return _state; }
  set { _state = value; }
}
private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension extensionObject;
global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
  { return global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing); }
}

 [global::System.Serializable, global::ProtoBuf.ProtoContract(Name=@"InputStateData")]
 public partial class InputStateData : global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible
{
public InputStateData() {}

private readonly global::System.Collections.Generic.List<InputState> _input = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<InputState>();
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, Name=@"input", DataFormat = global::ProtoBuf.DataFormat.Default)]
public global::System.Collections.Generic.List<InputState> input
{
  get { return _input; }
}

private global::ProtoBuf.IExtension extensionObject;
global::ProtoBuf.IExtension global::ProtoBuf.IExtensible.GetExtensionObject(bool createIfMissing)
  { return global::ProtoBuf.Extensible.GetExtensionObject(ref extensionObject, createIfMissing); }
}

}
```